Moving A Cloth Object After Running Cloth Sim
I am trying to get cloth in my scene, as a simple curtain. I've run a cloth sim under physics and under object data, I used shape keys. I hope that you are familiar with this method, if more info is needed to solve my question, please let me know.
My problem is that after creating this cloth curtain, I can't seem to move it around without my curtain becoming distorted. Is there a setting in the physics tab under cloth sim that will prevent this? What Am i missing?
I've attached two screenshots, a before and after. Before I attempt to move the cloth and after I attempt to move the cloth.



Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

if you are happy with the simulated shape of the curtains you need to apply the Cloth modifier. Then the mesh will keep its shape and you can move it around.
